# How do I get the contents of an [object Object] in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a payload of data that gets sent with some JSON and then uploaded to a database. When I try to write it to my database the field is [object Object]. This is what the JSON looks like:

```
{
    "version":"1.0",
    "event":"video_recorded",
    "data":{
        "videoName":"vsrtc1492808825_223",
        "audioCodec":"NellyMoser ASAO",
        "videoCodec":"H.264",
        "type":"FLV",
        "orientation":"landscape",
        "id":"315414",
        "dateTime":"2017-04-21 14:07:12",
        "timeZone":"America/Los_Angeles",
        "payload":"{\\\"ip\\\":111.111.111.11, \\\"env\\\": test}",
        "httpReferer":"https://app.surveygizmo.com/projects/previewbottom?id=3489282&__sgtarget=3&sLanguage=English&__sg_build_test=1&__sg_collab_test=1&__sg_tester=SW5mb0BNb29uc0FuYWx5dGljcy5jb20%3D&__sg_tester_name=TW9vbnMgQW5hbHl0aWNz&__sg_tester_id=351560&link_id=0&__sg_skip_actions=1&__ignore_entry_logic=1&?preview_frame=true"
    }
}
```

In the embed code JavaScript I pass this variable into the flashvars to get it added to the json:

```
var clientIP = '11.11.111.1111';
var payload_data = {"ip":clientIP, "env":"test"};
var flashvars = {qualityurl: "avq/300p.xml",accountHash:"randomstuff", eid:2, showMenu:"true", mrt:120,sis:0,asv:1,mv:0, payload: payload_data};
```

I have tried to select the correct key after decoding the entirety of the JSON:

```
$data = $_POST['payload'];
$retrieved_data = json_decode($data, true);
$ip_address = $retrieved_data['data']['payload'];
```

When I write $ip_address to my database it returns:

```
[object Object]
```

If I try to go one level deeper in my PHP:

```
$ip_address = $retrieved_data['data']['payload']['ip'];
```

It adds four entries into my database:

```
[
]
{ 
}
```

The documentation for the recorder https://addpipe.com/docs#sending-custom-data-using-payload-variable says to pass the custom JSON in between single quotes:

```
payload: '{"ip":clientIP, "env":"test"}'
```

If I try to write the entire payload to the database:

```
$ip_address = $retrieved_data['data']['payload'];
```

It writes the following to the field without showing the contents of the clientIP variable:

```
{\"ip\":clientIP,\"env\":\"test\"}
```

If I try to go a level deeper with this method:

```
$ip_address = $retrieved_data['data']['payload']['ip'];
```

I get the same four entry thing:

```
[
]
{
}
```

So I am stuck I don't know what else to try.

Im trying to get the info that is in here:

```
"payload":"{\\\"ip\\\":111.111.111.11, \\\"env\\\": test}"
```

Comment: `[object Object]` --- that's what you exactly received from the javascript: it's a `object Object` string.

Comment: I'd suggest `var_dump('<pre>' . $data . '</pre>')`; to see what is really being returned. Same thing could applied to `$retrieved_data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://addpipe.com/docs#sending-custom-data-using-payload-variable) you've provided a link to:

> You have two formating options in order to send the JSON correctly:
>
> - enclose the JSON in quotes and write the JSON normally: `payload:'{"a":"b"}'`
> - enclose the JSON in double quotes and escape the double quotes from inside the JSON `payload:"{\"a\":\"b\"}"`

This seems very clear:

```
var clientIP = '11.11.111.1111';
var payload_data = JSON.stringify({ip:clientIP, env:"test"});
var flashvars = {qualityurl: "avq/300p.xml",accountHash:"randomstuff", eid:2, showMenu:"true", mrt:120,sis:0,asv:1,mv:0, payload: payload_data};
```

However this is apparently not working. Until the issue is resolved on the remote server, you can try sending a delimited string and then parse it on the PHP side:

```
var clientIP = '11.11.111.1111';
var payload_data = clientIP + '|test';
var flashvars = {qualityurl: "avq/300p.xml",accountHash:"randomstuff", eid:2, showMenu:"true", mrt:120,sis:0,asv:1,mv:0, payload: payload_data};
```

Then in the PHP

```
$data = $_POST['payload'];
$retrieved_data = json_decode($data, true);
list($ip_address, $env) = explode("|", $retrieved_data['data']['payload']);
```

Comment: When I pass it this way it breaks the app and tells me I do not have a Webcam.

Comment: That seems strange. I suggest you find out what kind of data this provider is expecting, it's obviously not expecting an object of any kind.

Comment: If I put the `var payload_data = '{ip:clientIP, env:environment}'` then i can get the `{ip:clientIP, env:"test"}` back. But it wont let me pull info inside by calling [ip].

Comment: You're calling some kind of interface here, it must be documented. What kind of data is it expecting?

Comment: It says I can send data in JSON format https://addpipe.com/docs#sending-custom-data-using-payload-variable .

Comment: Trust me been and done that, the stringify is new, but the result is the same. If I Add the entire payload variable to my database `$payload = $retrieved_data['data']['payload'];` then it gives me `{\"ip\":\"108.234.176.17\",\"env\":\"test\"}`. If i try to pull just the ip by going a level deeper `$ip = retrieved_data['data']['payload']['ip'];` it just returns `{`. If I try to decode it again with `$somvar = json_decode($payload, true);` it returns nothing whatsoever.

Comment: Then you should contact the interface provider, or pass only strings. Perhaps a pipe-delimted string that you can explode.

Comment: What are you doing with `flashvars` after constructing it?

Comment: Yeah I am in contact with the providers founder but the time difference means a large lag between emails. The flashvars is getting sent to the providers server with the recorded video, they then extract the payload and add it to the JSON for their webhook service.

Comment: My guess is whatever method is being used to send it is treating it like a string and not JSON. I'll update my answer to suggest a delimited string.

Answer (score -1):

I've seen this sort of thing before, basically a JSON string stored as a string value for a key in a JSON object.  PHP treats this nested JSON string as a string, and doesn't decode it on the first pass, so you have to do that separately.  Try this:

```
$data = $_POST['payload'];
$retrieved_data = json_decode($data, true);
$ip_address_json = $retrieved_data['data']['payload'];

// Now decode the nested JSON string
$ip_address = json_decode($ip_address_json, true);
echo $ip_address['ip'];
```

Comment: Or one may suggest to resolve the issues with double encoding it on the client side :-)

Comment: I have tried this, and it is not grabbing anything, I attempted it by writing it to a .txt file rather than echo, but the effect should be the same.

Comment: What do you mean double encoding?

Comment: I mean the nested JSON is stored as a string, like this: `{"root": {"normalElement":"foo","nestedJsonElement":"{\"bar\":\"baz\"}"}}`